# Having trouble deploying a parse server to heroku. Using moralis parse server and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, heroku, parse-platform, moralis

This server runs fine locally using "yarn build yarn start" but when trying to deploy I am getting these errors. Cannot find anything on google so far that has worked. Any help would be much appreciated!!

```
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (yarn.lock)
remote:        yarn install v1.22.19
remote:        [1/4] Resolving packages...
remote:        [2/4] Fetching packages...
remote:        warning Pattern ["debug@>= 2.6.9 < 3.0.0 || >= ^3.1.0"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "/tmp/yarncache.VrWcZ/v6/npm-debug-3.2.7-integrity/node_modules/debug" as pattern ["debug@^3.1.0","debug@^3.2.7","debug@^3.2.7"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
remote:        error Command failed.
remote:        Exit code: 128
remote:        Command: git
remote:        Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads ssh://git@github.com/mongodb-js/mongodb-tools.git
remote:        Directory: /tmp/build_fa7e0e92
remote:        Output:
remote:        Host key verification failed.
remote:        fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
remote:
remote:        Please make sure you have the correct access rights
remote:        and the repository exists.
remote:        info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        Some possible problems:
```

I tried to deploy to heroku. Build fails due to "Host key verification failed" It looks like I do not have access to ssh://git@github.com/mongodb-js/mongodb-tools.git, but i'm not quite sure what that means

Comment: Hey there @luketorv, did you by any chance give your repository the right access to Heroku? that might be the issue here